# Access to getImageData from Greasemonkey script

Tags: html, greasemonkey, same-origin-policy

I want to implement a Greasemonkey script which scan each image on a page and makes some action depending on the image content. I'm going to use `getImageData` method of Canvas object to get the image content.

When I test my userscript with FireFox I get 'Security Error' exception which means that the userscript does not have access to original page's images.

Is there any workarounds?
What security context the user scripts are working in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). If you're trying to manipulate images from domains other than the one the site is hosted on, you will receive security errors.

You *can* work around this by using a proxy web server to feed you the image data via a base64 encoded string. There's a jQuery plugin [available here](http://www.maxnov.com/getimagedata/) that uses Google by default to feed you the strings, but it's limited to a certain amount of traffic per day and thus is not reliable out of the box. You can use their code (linked at the bottom of the page) on your own server to bypass this, though (which I have done with great success).

Comment: Not good fot me. It seems I have to implement desired functionality as a FireFox plugin.